# Cross controller update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a Create Action in a Controller (History) which receives a parameter of an ID from another table (Asset).

Once the view returns the data back to create the new History record I also need it to update a field in the Asset table.

I am not sure on the best practice to achieve this. Can/should a Create Action call an Edit Action on a different controller or can//should you access the Asset model in the History Controller and update using a LINQ expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it work using the LINQ option:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ServiceID,AssetID,Date,ContractorID,Notes")] ServiceHistory serviceHistory)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ServiceHistories.Add(serviceHistory);

        // Upadte Next Service Date
        var query = from r in db.Assets
               where r.AssetID == serviceHistory.AssetID
               select r;

        foreach (Asset r in query)
        {
            int freq = (int)r.ServiceFrequency;
            r.NextServiceDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(freq);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Assets", new { id = serviceHistory.AssetID });
    }

    ViewBag.AssetID = new SelectList(db.Assets, "AssetID", "Description", serviceHistory.AssetID);
    return View();

}
```

Please let me know if you think this is a bit of a hack and there is a better way.